# Two way binding is not working right in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5

Could somebody help with understands how I can do like this?

```
<app-tests-list
  [(ngModel)]="selectedTests"
  [(indeterminate)]="globalCheckbox.indeterminate"

  [(allSelection)]="globalCheckbox.value"
></app-tests-list>
```

In child component I do so

```
  @Input('indeterminate') _indeterminate: boolean;
  @Output('indeterminate') _indeterminateChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input('allSelection') _allSelection: boolean;
  @Output('allSelection') _allSelectionChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  setIndeterminate(value) {
    this._indeterminate = value;
    this._indeterminateChange.emit(this._indeterminate);
  }

  setAllSelection(value) {
    this._allSelection = value;
    this._allSelectionChange.emit(this._allSelection);
  }
```

But in parent component I can use it only like this

```
<app-tests-list
  [(ngModel)]="selectedTests"
  [indeterminate]="globalCheckbox.indeterminate"
  (indeterminate)="globalCheckbox.indeterminate = $event"

  [allSelection]="globalCheckbox.value"
  (allSelection)="globalCheckbox.value = $event"></app-tests-list>
```

But it is not so beautiful that I expected :)

Comment: Could you please let me know **WHAT YOU WANT?**

Comment: Sure. I want to use custom two way binding and to keep html clear and clean.
I want to use like `[(allSelection)]="globalCheckbox.value"` not like `[allSelection]="globalCheckbox.value"
  (allSelection)="globalCheckbox.value = $event"`

Comment: `allSelection` is an event not a property .

Comment: @RameshRajendran do you have any idea how I could I convert it to the property?
I found the tutorial (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) how it could be done but for AngularJS2. I suppose it should be working for AngularJS5 but it isn't. Is there any way to make it work?